# Find days with available slots for a specific booking duration

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with bookings like that:

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| date       | time     | duration |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 2014-05-10 | 13:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-13 | 09:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-13 | 10:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-13 | 13:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-13 | 17:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-13 | 18:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-14 | 09:00:00 | 720      |
| 2014-05-15 | 09:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-15 | 11:00:00 | 60       |
| 2014-05-15 | 12:00:00 | 60       |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

So, I can have bookings of one hour of duration or all-day booking.

Now, I want to create a new booking of one hour, and I want to know which days of an specific month have free time. I don't want to know all free slots (like other SO questions), I just want to know what days can allocate this booking.
So, knowing the opening and closing time, the new booking duration and the month, I need a SQL query that can return something like this:

```
+------------+
| free_days  |
+------------+
| 2014-05-01 |
| ...        |
| 2014-05-08 |
| 2014-05-09 |
| 2014-05-10 |
| 2014-05-11 |
| 2014-05-12 |
| 2014-05-13 |
| 2014-05-15 |
| ...        |
| 2014-05-31 |
+------------+
```

2014-05-14 is missing because have one all-day booking, but other days can be missing if have, for example, 12 one-hour' bookings.

I've looked other SO articles, but I'm unable to adapt it. Any idea ?

Comment: No database running on my machine, but if I understand the question correctly, something like `SELECT date AS free_days FROM bookings WHERE SUM(duration) < 720 GROUP BY date` should be close. You want the days where the total bookings are below a threshold.

Comment: I think a database redesign would help you with this.  Assuming 1 hour slots, create with a table of all available slots.  Include a booked_by column.  Then you can check for records where the booked by is either null, or has a default value.

Comment: Thanks @JohnC, this is very close, but I changed it to use HAVING instead of SUM, because you can't use SUM in WHERE. But, this return days with free time only if that day is already present in the table. Using my example booking table, this return days 10, 13 and 15. I want all days from a month, including those not present in table and which have all day free. I can add it after the query using PHP, but a complete SQL query would be perfect.

Comment: Ah, right. That's what I get for working off the top of my head. I don't think there's any query that can produce data not in the table, though. The closest I can think of would be to create a table with every date to join to your useful table. Dan's idea has a lot of potential, too, if feasible. You can even create a View to replace the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I have only tested this in Sql server, should be very similar though I think:

```
create table #AllDatesInRange
(
     date datetime
)

declare @maxDate datetime 
declare @currentdate datetime 

set @maxDate = (select max(date) from table_1)
set @currentdate = (select min(date) from table_1)

while @currentdate <= @maxDate
begin 
     insert #AllDatesInRange(date) values(@currentdate)
     set @currentdate = dateadd(day,1,@currentdate)
End 

--missing dates 
 SELECT A.date, 'Free All Day' as [Free slots] from #AllDatesInRange A 
 LEFT JOIN table_1 B ON 
 A.date = B.date 
 WHERE B.date IS NULL 

 UNION All

 select date, 'One or more slots free' as [Free slots] FROM table_1
 group by Date
 having sum(duration) < 720
```